# How to store decimal.Decimal in array.array in Python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, decimal

How can I create an `array.array` of `Decimal`? I want to do accurate float calculation, and I am storing numbers inside `array.array`. So I want to store `Decimal` inside `array.array`. I don't want to use Numpy for this.

I have tried setting the type code to `f` but it just converts the `Decimal` into `float`, and I don't want it to be converted! (It will lose precision)

```
import array
from decimal import Decimal

new = array.array("f", [Decimal(1.1)])

# These two show different results!
print(Decimal(1.1)) # 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
print(new[0]) # 1.100000023841858
```

Comment: can you add the code which you tried?

Comment: I've added some details about the problem.

Comment: The correct way to use a Decimal is `Decimal("1.1")`. And is does print the exact value: `print(Decimal('1.1'))`  gives `1.1`. Unfortunately `array` is restricted to intrinsic types. And once you use `float` or even `double` the array will convert the exact decimals to `float` or `double` with all the possible rounding problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
new = array.array("d", [Decimal(1.1)])
```

Double should have more decimal points.

Comment: Beware. This is an array of `double`. Do not do this if `Decimal` are needed.

Comment: Yes, dependable on which operations he wants to perform after, he will perhaps want to keep Decimal. But in the example, it was just printing it out, so I don't think this will be a problem.

Comment: I'd assume he is using `Decimal` on purpose, so this is no solution to the question. OTOH the OP selected this as the correct answer, so he probably does not care about using `Decimal` at all.